# input day,month,year and store in a seperate structure

Tags: c++

Currently i am working on a task that need me to store the date in to structure(day,month,year) but i dont know how to seperate it when user enter all in one line

```
struct Date
{

int day;
int month;
int year;
}hire_date;

int main()
{

cout<<"Enter employee hired date(dd/mm/yyyy) :";

cin>>hire_date.day;
cin>>hire_date.month;
cin>>hire_date.year;`
}
```

Comment: Hello, as it is, this question is unclear. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question.

Comment: For your case instead of asking "Enter employee hired date(dd/mm/yyyy) :", you might want to ask 3 questions such as "Enter employee hired day(dd) :"

Comment: Do you simply want `cin >> hire_date.day >> hire_date.month >> hire_date.year;` ?

Comment: @macroland is there anyway i can avoid asking 3 question

Comment: @JesperJuhl it does't work but yeah i want somthing like that

Comment: It works with input such as "15 12 2018". if you want different separators than space you could simply read the entire line into a string (see `getline()`) and then tokenize/parse it yourself using whatever format you want.

Comment: If user enters with blanks in between then JesperJuhl's suggestion should work

Comment: for user friendly is there no way i can do it my way ? @JesperJuhl

Comment: look at stringstream then. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently saw the nice answer of Kerrek for a similar problem in [SO: Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/7478597) with an additional comment for the separator trick.

So, I looked for this and transformed it to your standard input requirement (which was actually easy and less effort):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Date {
  int day, month, year;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout<< "Enter employee hired date (dd/mm/yyyy): ";
  Date hireDate; char sep1, sep2;
  std::cin >> hireDate.day >> sep1 >> hireDate.month >> sep2 >> hireDate.year;
  if (std::cin && sep1 == '/' && sep2 == '/') {
    std::cout << "Got: "
      << hireDate.day << '/' << hireDate.month << '/' << hireDate.year << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: dd/mm/yyyy expected!\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
Enter employee hired date (dd/mm/yyyy): 28/08/2018
Got: 28/8/2018
```

<kbd>[**Life Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/oZDUXB)</kbd>

**Note:**

This doesn't consider a verification of input numbers (whether they form a valid date) nor that the number of input digits match the format. For the latter, it would probably better to follow the hint concerning `std::getline()` i.e. get input as `std::string` and verify first `char` by `char` that syntax is correct.